# ModuleNotFoundError: cx_Oracle

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

I've spent the last two days trying to diagnose this and find a solution through Google. None of the search results have answers that apply to me. Hoping for some help.

I have a very simple program to set up a database connection an Oracle database using SQLAlchemy. I am using SQLAlchemy because my app will use the ORM features.

```
import datetime
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

try:
    engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://dbusername:dbpassword@dbtns')
    session = sessionmaker()
    session.configure(bind=engine)
    rs = session.execute("SELECT sysdate FROM dual")
finally:
    print(datetime.datetime.now)
```

The error message in Spyder says,

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

pip freeze shows among all the other packages listed:
SQLAlchemy==1.1.15
cx-oracle==6.0.3

My setup:

- Running Python 2.7. Windows 10 64-bit.
- I have a 64-bit Oracle client installed and sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files.
- The PATH environment points to the Oracle client root directory.
- I have both Python 2.7 and 3.6 installed.
- Spyder is running under the 2.7 environment.
- Conda version 4.3.21

I am at a complete loss on what to do next. Pretty much all other answers say to make sure you have an Oracle client installed. It is installed and it works just fine with other programs that need database connectivity.

Comment: You can correctly use sqlplus from the command line to connect to an oracle database? That'd suggest the client libs are installed correctly. Are you sure your virtualenv is activated, so that cx_Oracle **is** available to your version of python? Try running python and typing `import cx_Oracle`.

Comment: What happens when you `import cx_Oracle`?

Comment: @alvits Same error when I explicitly add import cx_Oracle to the code in the question.

Comment: It means you are running the wrong python. Run the python that has `cx_Oracle`.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton I opened up an Anaconda prompt and made sure to switch to the 2.7 environment (verified by the environment name next to the command prompt). Then typing import cx_oracle in python, still shows the same error: module not found.

Comment: I finally gave up, blew away the 2.7 environment and created it again. The 2.7 environment I had been using was 2.7.12. This new one is 2.7.13 (may or may not be important). Works like a charm now. Can't explain why. Thank you JoshSmeaton and alvits for your questions. You helped me realize this was something weird that probably required a new environment.